# Better way to test constructors - phpunit

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, zend-framework, phpunit

This is the test case I have written to test a constructor of class. Is this wrong and is there any other better way ?

```
/**
 * Set values of an edge
 *
 * @param string|int $point1 starting point of an edge
 * @param string|int $point2 end point of an edge
 * @param int $value of an edge
 */
public function __construct($point1, $point2, $value)
{
    $this->setPoint1($point1);
    $this->setPoint2($point2);
    $this->setValue($value);
}

/**
 * Test for class constructor
 */
public function testConstructor()
{
    $edgeObj = new Edge('x', 'y', 15.25);
    $this->assertEquals('x', $edgeObj->getPoint1());
    $this->assertEquals('y', $edgeObj->getPoint2());
    $this->assertEquals(15.25, $edgeObj->getValue());
}
```

Comment: You may also wish to assert that `$edgeObj` is an object of type `Edge`... if the constructor has failed, then it may not be

Comment: I'm testing getters above to test the constructor, is that wrong ?

Comment: That depends.... on the additional detail of the class, and exactly what the getters do (any additional logic beyond returning the property value).... you're also testing the setters as well (and those should probably be tested independently as well if your values are supposed to be restricted to int|string.... otherwise it's the most practical test

Comment: Your test is good enough.